# Vba to reference a cell but remain static in the new cell

Tags: excel, vba

My workbook has data that is automatically loaded in from yahoo finance. The data is constantly being refreshed. I need a formula that can take the referenced cell and produce the number value of that cell without updating whenever the referenced cell does. For example: Cell G3 will say 40.75 for the stock value and I need D2 to say 40.75 except that it will remain 40.75 when G3 updates to the new price.

I have tried using `=Numbervalue($G$3)` but that still updates when the data refreshes.

*UPDATE*

This is the VBA Code that I have to paste the Date and Time in the active cell (Which is correct) then it will paste the price (G3) in the cell of D2.

```vb
Sub TimeStamp()
'
' TimeStamp Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+T
'
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(L1,N1)"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("D2").Value = Range("G3").Value
End Sub
```

My problem is that I need the `Range("D2").Value = Range("G3").Value` part of the code to recognize the next empty cell in Column D. Currently, it will replace whatever data is already in the D2 cell.

Comment: You need a VBA solution for this - a macro which takes the value from G3, and drops it into D2. Go to View > Macros > Record Macro and record yourself clicking on G3, copying with CTRL + C, moving to D2, and pasting with CTRL + V. Then you can run that macro whenever "some event" happens, such as when you manually select the macro.

Comment: so what determines the initial value for D2? when the workbook is opened? Just whatever the first value is?

Comment: If you create a pivot table and source those cells (G3, etc) then the number won't change when the source changes, until you refresh the pivot table itself. Think that would do it for you?

Comment: @SamHolder its is determined when I place the formula. The other cell is set with a macro to record the time when the data is refreshed. Once refreshed, this formula will take the G3 data and make it static so that I can plot the data on a graph over time.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I will try the recording and let you know.

Comment: Why don't you just include in your macro that records the time to write the time stamp into G3? ie `ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Value2 = TimeStamp`. If `G3` is not necessarily the cell to receive the value, but rather you want go to the next empty cell in your column then you can adapt the range reference accordingly. Doesn't make sense in my mind to create a separate macro to copy the data again. Regards,

Comment: @nbayly The timestamp is used on a completely different cell. It is used in the cells in Column A. This record the current date and time when the data is refreshed. The next column im trying to get to be the stock price at the time that the data was refreshed. G3 has that stock price but that is the one that is connected to Yahoo finance. D2 is where the first stock price at the first available time will be recorded. It would be amazing if I can get the macro to do both but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write on your macro to the first empty row on column `D` by replacing this line:

```
Range("D2").Value = Range("G3").Value
```

With this one:

```
ActiveSheet.Columns(4).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value2 = Range("G3").Value2
```

Regards,

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I replaced the original line with that one and all it does is return the date and time which is what the first part of the macro does. It doesn't return the value to the first available cell of column D. Or at least it isn't for me.

Comment: Where in your code is the value for `G3` written? Doesn't show in the code snippet. Can you place a break point in the line I suggested and review the values and the results? Does it do anything in Column D?

Comment: I just realized... the code that you gave me works except it is populating the value into Column T instead of Column D. In addition, it also starts on row 27 rather than row 2

Comment: You are right. `xlCellTypeLastCell` takes you to the most bottom right cell of the range of used cells. Not the right process. Please try this alternate solution: `ActiveSheet.Columns(4).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value2 = Range("G3").Value2`. Regards,